# To fetch a range of values from the user given value using pymongo and mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I was trying to get a set of values (min, max) from the user and use it as range to fetch result from database.

```
def range(min_age,max_age):
    query={"$and":[
                    {"age":{"$gte":min_age}},
                    {"age":{"$lte":max_age}}
                  ]}
    mate=students.find(query)
    for age in mate:
        printer.pprint(age)

range (20,25)
```

Comment: Your query looks fine, only remember that the output of `find` is a cursor, and not a list. So if you iterate over it once, you can not do it anymore.